# How to deal with this type of nut

Tags: nut, wheel-bearing

My wheel bearings are due, and I ordered a new set.

Up to now, I thought I have regular nuts on my hubs which are secured by some kind of sleeve, which in turn is dented into the axial groove of the hub.

When the set arrived, I noticed that this isn't true, there is just a specially shaped nut, as seen in the image. Due to perspective, the new nut looks bigger, but this isn't true, it hast exactly the size of the old nut. Except one point: The sleeve part of the old nut doesn't have a tread, so the material is quite thin and can easily be dented into the groove.

In the new nut, the tread reaches to the front of the sleeve, making the material thicker and more rigid. I guess it will need more force to dent the sleeve into the groove.

So, my questions are:

- Is it correct that the tread reaches to the front of the sleeve part?
- What is the correct way to dent the sleeve? I think hammering could do some damage...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

They look exactly the same. The threading is probably the same on both nuts.

Use a hammer and flat head chisel to peen the new nut. These nuts aren't meant to be reused and as long as you're hammering into the groove it's fine

Comment: The questioner explicitly wrote that the threading is _not_ the same, though.

Comment: @JdeBP The OP did not write that. Read it again.

Comment: Take your own advice.  *The sleeve part of the old nut doesn't have a thread* is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the nuts are equivalent, the old nut may have a separate flat washer, that is now built -in to the new nut. The difference of the locking sleeve is that the sleeve on the old nut was machined with clearance so it did not touch the thread - the sleeve on the new nut has an integral thread and you still dent or peen (using a hammer and punch or chisel) the sleeve into the groove on the axle once the bearing play is correct.